How to replace texts in PDF?
For my project, I need to replace texts in PDF with JS. I made progress but PDF outputs of professional programs like Word or LibreWriter didn't have any understandable and replacable text. What do I need to do?
basic raw PDF file (just a section):
4 0 obj
<< /Length 132 >>
stream
BT
/F1 12 Tf
50 150 Td
(This is a simple PDF) Tj
0 -20 Td
/F2 12 Tf
(This is bold text) Tj
0 -20 Td
/F3 12 Tf
(This is italic text) Tj
ET
endstream
endobj
at above we can see texts easily but PDF's of Word, etc. didn't have real text. I need to know how to parse the files. Any articles or help will be helpful thank you so much for reading.
I tried to parse and replace with fs stream, with constant texts it is possible but with inputs come from other files or user is not working. Here is the basic code:
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

var pdfData = null;
let parsedText = null;
let fontMap = {};


function readPDFFile(filePath) {
    try {
        pdfData = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
        return pdfData;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Could not read the PDF file: ${err.message}`);
        return null;
    }
}

function parsePDF() {
    if (!pdfData) {
        console.error('No PDF data available.');
        return null;
    }

    const lines = pdfData.split('\n');
    const text = [];
    fontMap = {};

    let inStream = false;
    let currentFont = null;

    lines.forEach(line => {
        line = line.trim();

        if (line === "stream") {
            inStream = true;
        } else if (line === "endstream") {
            inStream = false;
        } else if (line.startsWith('/BaseFont')) {
            const match = /\/BaseFont\s\/(\w+)(?:-Bold|-Oblique)?/.exec(line);
            if (match) {
                currentFont = match[1];
                fontMap[currentFont] = match[0];
            }
        } else if (inStream) {
            const match = /\((.*)\) Tj/.exec(line);
            if (match) {
                text.push({ text: match[1], font: currentFont });
            }
        }
    });

    parsedText = text;
    return parsedText;
}

function processParsedText(style) {
    if (!parsedText) {
        console.error('No parsed text available.');
        return null;
    }

    const styleMap = {
        Italic: '-Oblique',
        Bold: '-Bold'
    };

    if (!styleMap[style]) {
        console.error('Invalid style provided.');
        return null;
    }

    parsedText = parsedText.map(item => {
        if (item.font) {
            item.font = `${item.font}${styleMap[style]}`;
        }
        return item;
    });

    return parsedText;
}

function replace(parsedText, newText) {
    if (!parsedText) {
        console.error('No parsed text provided.');
        return null;
    }

    if (!newText || newText.length !== parsedText.length) {
        console.error('Invalid new text provided.');
        return null;
    }

    const newContent = parsedText.map((item, index) => ({
        text: newText[index],
        font: item.font
    }));

    let updatedPDF = pdfData;
    parsedText.forEach((item, index) => {
        const regex = new RegExp(`\\(${item.text}\\) Tj`, 'g');
        updatedPDF = updatedPDF.replace(regex, `(${newContent[index].text}) Tj`);
    });

    pdfData = updatedPDF;

    return newContent;
}

function saveToFile(filename) {
    if (!pdfData || !parsedText) {
        console.error('No data available.');
        return;
    }

    const combinedContent = `${pdfData}`;
    fs.writeFileSync(filename, combinedContent, 'utf8');
}

function processPDF(inputFilePath, outputFilePath) {
    readPDFFile(inputFilePath);
    parsePDF();
    saveToFile(outputFilePath);
}

module.exports = {
    readPDFFile,
    parsePDF,
    processParsedText,
    replace,
    saveToFile,
    processPDF,
    getPdfData: () => pdfData,
    getParsedText: () => parsedText
};


Thank you for your great help! So how can I convert PDF -> RTF? After posting this question, I've looked for PDF alternatives. I can convert PDF -> RTF -> PDF if there is way to.

To decompress a PDF into plain text such as ANSI or JSON using JavaScript consider how you might use coherent cpdf JS API.
I use a command line approach to such tasks, as it is easier for one off editing. But for programmable approach you would need the API library.
As an example a text.pdf file (I know well) will in encoded format look like this.
2 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 361>>
stream
xM‘Ñn‚0†ïû'Ù…xQjQ”-ñÂeš]˜ÌL^ Ð"Ý€’Ò§ bB_Ïéþóóž!Y, •°Â÷ž@ZàT Ý¤êê`¥síc…Q¶3u˜›š5Ê±OÓ§†Iáû2'YŒ­÷WQ·•
[YÌgÄË­Qî¦ð RÎ¡N8ŸAäOIðê?7I¦:¡xêƒïˆÇŽ@ ðÍ3$O-' tÝ(ÃRœL@èò®—#=ô$B´ï5‹×èãYž/ÆhÅEn@4Æ•ÊÂéã0mµ«:ìð)‚›bì0GÌÆd?*wC’H¬B£Ë¶õÁ½xÝm4îœ}ˆÜÿŽÊ|589ë‹+á¬ò?«À•ºƒBcðG‰„7½v%ì¤É|+!•_€Æ@Gc!¯tþû0Ö÷}(|÷`LäÖdÂ1ÓTºQ¬Ã‘Ý…¥«+ÔÙ§$BCëMÅÀÇ*r&ÿ#É¤Å
endstream
endobj

But as editable text (cpdf -decompress -no-preserve-objstm out.pdf -o text.pdf) it can be seen as.
10 0 obj
<</Length 588>>
stream
BT 15 800 Td 40 TL/1 18 Tf(PlainText = http://foersom.com/net/HowTo/data/OoPdfFormExample.pdf)'/1 16 Tf 40 TL(12  letters.)' 20 TL(9)' 27 20 Td(letters.)' -27 0 Td(A)' 25 20 Td(a)' 17 20 Td(a)' 18 20 Td(a)' 23 20 Td(a)' -72 20 Td(b)' 58 20 Td(b)' -35 20 Td(c)' 17 20 Td(d)' 26.5 20 Td(r)' -58 20 Td(r)' 40 TL(goto page in another PDF)' 20 TL(Also plain text = https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf#page=2)' 25 TL/1 11 Tf 120 140 Td(Sign and Secure this file.txt as a PDF with Adobe Reader)' -5 -40 Td(or click https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/online/sign-pdf.html)' ET 220 680 150 50 re S
endstream
endobj

Or JSON (cpdf in.pdf -output-json -utf8 -output-json-parse-content-streams -o out.json).
{
      "S": [
        {},
        [
          [ "BT" ],
          [ { "F": 15.0 }, { "F": 800.0 }, "Td" ],
          [ { "F": 40.0 }, "TL" ],
          [ "/1", { "F": 18.0 }, "Tf" ],
          [
            "PlainText = http://foersom.com/net/HowTo/data/OoPdfFormExample.pdf",
            "'"
          ],
          [ "/1", { "F": 16.0 }, "Tf" ],
          [ { "F": 40.0 }, "TL" ],
          [ "12  letters.", "'" ],
          [ { "F": 20.0 }, "TL" ],
          [ "9", "'" ],
          [ { "F": 27.0 }, { "F": 20.0 }, "Td" ],
          [ "letters.", "'" ],
          [ { "F": -27.0 }, { "F": 0.0 }, "Td" ],
          [ "A", "'" ],
          [ { "F": 25.0 }, { "F": 20.0 }, "Td" ],
          [ "a", "'" ],
          [ { "F": 17.0 }, { "F": 20.0 }, "Td" ],
          [ "a", "'" ],
          [ { "F": 18.0 }, { "F": 20.0 }, "Td" ],
          [ "a", "'" ],
          [ { "F": 23.0 }, { "F": 20.0 }, "Td" ],
          [ "a", "'" ],
          [ { "F": -72.0 }, { "F": 20.0 }, "Td" ],
          [ "b", "'" ],
          [ { "F": 58.0 }, { "F": 20.0 }, "Td" ],
          [ "b", "'" ],
          [ { "F": -35.0 }, { "F": 20.0 }, "Td" ],
          [ "c", "'" ],
          [ { "F": 17.0 }, { "F": 20.0 }, "Td" ],
          [ "d", "'" ],
          [ { "F": 26.5 }, { "F": 20.0 }, "Td" ],
          [ "r", "'" ],
          [ { "F": -58.0 }, { "F": 20.0 }, "Td" ],
          [ "r", "'" ],
          [ { "F": 40.0 }, "TL" ],
          [ "goto page in another PDF", "'" ],
          [ { "F": 20.0 }, "TL" ],
          [
            "Also plain text = https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf#page=2",
            "'"
          ],
          [ { "F": 25.0 }, "TL" ],
          [ "/1", { "F": 11.0 }, "Tf" ],
          [ { "F": 120.0 }, { "F": 140.0 }, "Td" ],
          [ "Sign and Secure this file.txt as a PDF with Adobe Reader", "'" ],
          [ { "F": -5.0 }, { "F": -40.0 }, "Td" ],
          [
            "or click https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/online/sign-pdf.html",
            "'"
          ],
          [ "ET" ],
          [
            { "F": 220.0 },
            { "F": 680.0 },
            { "F": 150.0 },
            { "F": 50.0 },
            "re"
          ],
          [ "S" ]
        ]
      ]

Thus text is easier to edit (when done carefully) but either
JSON (cpdf -j in.json -o out.pdf) or TXT (cpdf pdf.txt -o text2.pdf)
can be reversed into the compressed.pdf format.
To show the power of the JS version. There is a demo rotate page by 10 degrees at https://coherentpdf.com/coherentpdfjs/index.html

The main difficulty you face is that Word will not output simple PDF thus the first line of your example text from Word will likely as text be decompressed as,
BT
0 Tr
/F1 15.969700 Tf
1 0 0.000000 -1 120.000000 108.800003 Tm
[<0037>-0.097656<004B>-0.097656<004C>-0.097656<0056>-0.097656<0003>-0.097656<004C>-0.097656<0056>-0.097656<0003>-0.097656<0044>-0.097656<0003>-0.097656<0056>-0.097656<004C>-0.097656<0050>-0.097656<0053>-0.097656<004F>-0.097656<0048>-0.097656<0003>-0.097656<0033>-0.097656<0027>-0.097656<0029>-0.097656] TJ
ET

Where Microsoft tend to use <0003> as a 16bit space character and normally use kerning between all the characters. and most libraries will find that almost impossible to overcome.
In JSON format that first line will be,
          [ "BT" ],
          [ { "I": 0 }, "Tr" ],
          [ "/F1", { "F": 15.9697 }, "Tf" ],
          [
            { "F": 1.0 },
            { "F": 0.0 },
            { "F": 0.0 },
            { "F": -1.0 },
            { "F": 120.0 },
            { "F": 108.800003 },
            "Tm"
          ],
          [
            [
              "\u00007",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u0000K",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u0000L",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u0000V",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u0000\u0003",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u0000L",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u0000V",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u0000\u0003",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u0000D",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u0000\u0003",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u0000V",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u0000L",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u0000P",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u0000S",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u0000O",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u0000H",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u0000\u0003",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u00003",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u0000'",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u0000)",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 }
            ],
            "TJ"
          ],
          [ "ET" ],

Where \u00007 is T and both the is as part of This & is can be seen repeated twice as,
              "\u0000L",
              { "F": -0.09765600000000001 },
              "\u0000V",

